# Boosting bluetooth audio / realising how does it work

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, headset

I want to boost the audio output over bluetooth on android device (Xperia Z1 running 4.4), but I can't find a file where the output level is designed. All audio devices are defined and configured in mixer_paths.xml like speaker, anc headphones, headphones, various mic's etc. Bluetooth IS there, but it looks weird for me...

http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/dy/k8/1z/pfrpai.jpg
         -screenshot of that

It looks like nothing would be defined regarding volumes or anything...
My only idea is that bluetooth audio receiver is sending it's own signal that defines max volume on sync with the device, allright if it's that way(I'm only guessing - let me know if I'm wrong) then there has to be a way to work-around that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the mixer_paths.xml file actually is used on the Z1? On XPeria phones running 4.1 (and 4.2 IIRC) the mixer paths were configured in another file; the ALSA UCM file (usually has a name that starts with snd_soc_msm, and should be located somewhere under /system/etc/). I haven't checked on phones running later versions of Android.

Comment: Yup. I'm sure of that. mixer_paths.xml is used on 4.4 and taiko files etc in /snd_soc_msm/ were used in 4.2/4.3. It doesn't really matters for me which file will be modified etc. as they are basically the same, just written in a different way - percentage of max value instead of the actual value for audio output for example.